# PrivateFontCollection Failing to Load Some Fonts

Tags: asp.net, fonts, privatefontcollection

I'm using a custom font which loads fine locally, but whn I upload it to my web server, a default fallback is used. No exception is thrown though, which I fine bizarre.

Here's what I'm using to load the font in `Application_Start` in `global.asax`:

```
try {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        var fontNames = Directory.GetFiles(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/fonts/labels/"));
        var pfc = AppCache.GetCachedFonts(); // static class, returns PFC from the HttpContext's cache
        fontNames.ForEach(f =>{
                                  try {
                                      pfc.AddFontFile(f);
                                  } catch(Exception ex) {
                                      Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                                  }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
    }
```

Elmah logs nothing though. Out of maybe 15 fonts I'm using, around half just fail silently. I'm not sure what to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by trying to use an unsupported variant of a font. Eg: Bold when the TTF only includes regular.